# How to get body of response by HTTP POST request via library request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I make HTTP POST request via library request, but cant to get BODY of response

In the console log, I see the correct answer but function `getBlock` rerun 0

```
class BlockExplorer {
    private readonly request = require("request");
    private readonly options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://example.com',
        headers:
        {
            Host: 'example.com'',
            Authorization: 'Basic basicBasicBasic=',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        json: true
    };

    async init() {
        const blockNum: Number = await this.getBlock();
        console.log(`Block num: ${blockNum}`);
    }

    private async getBlock() {
        let blockcount: Number = 0;
        var options = {
            body: { jsonrpc: '2.0', method: 'getblockcount', params: [] },
            ...this.options
        };

        await this.request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);
            console.log(body.result);
            blockcount = body.result;
        });

        return blockcount;
    }
}

new BlockExplorer().init();
```

My console log:

```
Block num: 0
617635
```

Comment: `await this.request()` does not work because `request()` does not return a promise.  Instead, use the `request-promise` module and get rid of the callback.  Or, since `request()` is in maintenance mode and no longer getting new features, switch to the `got()` module which already works with promises.

Comment: Thank you - it's working correct - just use `request-promise`

Comment: @jfriend00 please make your comment as an answer

Comment: Per your request, I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

await `this.request()` does not work because `request()` does not return a promise so therefore the `await` does nothing useful.

Instead, use the `request-promise` module and get rid of the callback.

Or, since `request()` is in maintenance mode and no longer getting new features, switch to the `got()` module which already works with promises.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

private async getBlock() {
    let blockcount: Number = 0;
    var options = {
        body: { jsonrpc: '2.0', method: 'getblockcount', params: [] },
        ...this.options
    };

    let body = await rp(options);
    console.log(body.result);
    blockcount = body.result;

    return blockcount;
}
```

---

**EDIT Jan, 2020 - request() module in maintenance mode**

FYI, the `request` module and its derivatives like [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) are now in maintenance mode and will not be actively developed to add new features.  You can read more about the reasoning [here](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode).  There is a list of alternatives in [this table](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode#alternativestorequest) with some discussion of each one.  I have been using [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) myself and it's built from the beginning to use promises and is simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `request` call. It is callback style. THis means that return blockcount will be executed first and `blockcount = body.result;` will be executed when asyn call is complete. You have two alternatives here

- Either convert the callback style to promise and get the results in a variable.
- OR return the response inside your callback.